# Input File Does Not Output? For Loop

Tags: c++, input, printf

I was told to build a program that has to output the line each time the text file contains '@'. This is my code, it told to must have a nested loop. Why does the program not print the text file? Is there a mistake I made? Thank you!

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
ifstream fin;
string I;
string D="filecontainingemails.txt";

cout <<"Enter input filename [default: fileContainingEmails.txt]: ";
getline (cin, I);
fin.open(I.c_str());
if (I.empty())
    {I=D;}

while (true)
{
    if (!fin.good()) break;
    string linefromfile;
    getline(fin, linefromfile);
    for (int i=0; i<linefromfile.length(); i++)
    {
        if(linefromfile[i] == '@')
            cout << linefromfile <<endl;
    }
}
fin.close();

string J;
string E="copyPasteMyEmails.txt";
cout <<"Enter output filename [default: copyPasteMyEmails.txt]: ";
getline (cin, J);

if (J.empty())
    {J=E;}
}
```

Comment: where you copying the words into a file??? you just printing it with `cout`

Comment: inside the for loop shouldn't it print the text file to the command prompt?

Comment: please provide sample input, desired output and actual output.

Comment: sample input:
 Bach  Dan  (925) 685-1230 x2800  DBach@dvc.edu  Math and Computer Science  Mathematics

Brecha  Jane  (925) 685-1230 x2801  JBrecha@dvc.edu  Math and Computer Science  Mathematics

desired output: 
<td align="left"><a href="mailto:RBurns@dvc.edu"><IMG src="mail.gif" alt="RBurns@dvc.edu"></a></td>

no actual output. when I press enter the program just ends.

Comment: Are you typing the file name in each time? You currently set the filename to the default *after* you have tried to open it.

Comment: yeah I am supposed to be using the default text file. Is there something wrong with using the default?

Comment: @xamfifa You only set "I" to the default *after* you have already tried to open it. So if you thought you were using the default file, you aren't.

Comment: yeah thats right, I fixed it. Now I just can't traverse the input file. The prompt is something like this "" If a line contains the character@more than once,it should be printed once for each. If a line contains no@at all, it should NOT be printed." Is my code wrong?

Answer (score 0):

These lines of code:

```
cout <<"Enter input filename [default: fileContainingEmails.txt]: ";
getline (cin, I);
fin.open(I.c_str());
if (I.empty())
    {I=D;}
```

currently you get a file name from the user, then try to open it. After that, if the user has entered a empty string, you change the file name. That is too late, as the file open has already failed.

Just move the file open to be after the change to default. Change it to something like this:

```
cout <<"Enter input filename [default: fileContainingEmails.txt]: ";
getline (cin, I);
if (I.empty())
    {I=D;}
fin.open(I.c_str());
```

Comment: oh yeah! I should have put the open in the bottom. It finally inputs! One question: if(linefromfile[i] == '@') does this code works on identifying if there is a "@" character in each line and print it? because my current output is just the whole text file. Thank you so much!

Comment: It should work, do you have lines without '@' signs? Note that it will print multiple times if the line has multiple '@' symbols in it, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: The prompt actually says to " If a line contains the character@more than once,it should be printed once for each. If a line contains no@at all, it should NOT be printed." So I am confused as of why my output is just the unmodified text file.

Comment: sample input: Bach Dan (925) 685-1230 x2800 DBach@dvc.edu Math and Computer Science Mathematics Brecha Jane (925) 685-1230 x2801 JBrecha@dvc.edu Math and Computer Science Mathematics 

desired output: <td align="left"><a href="mailto:RBurns@dvc.edu"><IMG src="mail.gif" alt="RBurns@dvc.edu"></a></td>

I do not understand how the output could be like that. If it is not much trouble, do you mind shedding a light?

Comment: You might need to put that into your question (or better still, a new question, as this one has been answered). I can't tell in the comments where the newlines are meant to be - it looks like every line has an @, so I would expect to see every line in the output - are you supposed to just output the email addresses with the same HTML around each one?

Comment: If you just want to output words with @ in them, use `fin >> linefromfile;` instead of `getline(fin, linefromfile);`. This will read one word at a time.

Comment: alright I guess I will ask this into a question, thanks for all your help! just a quick question, why do you think that once I put fin >> linefromfile, it just prints all the '@' s and not the full sentence? Also I have no idea where the html came from.